# How can I make express do checksum-based caching?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, caching, express

I'm aware of Express' `maxAge` directive for static content:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: 86400000 }));
```

However I'd like to set up a system where:

- Browsers cache any resource that has not changed
- Browsers fetch the latest version of resources that have changed

I understand this is normally done with checksums, ie: **serve all resources with a checksum as part of their URL**. Old URLs are cached forever, new content means new URLs.

**How can I set this up in express?**

Comment: Is this not what vanilla "Last-Modified" header based caching does?

Answer (score 3):

Some research shows that this is called **fingerprinting**. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark (that doc is for Rails, but HTTP concepts are identical to node of course).

[Node Static Asset](https://github.com/bminer/node-static-asset) does this for express.

```
var staticAsset = require('static-asset');
app.use(staticAsset(__dirname + "/public/") );
```

Then in a template:

```
<script src="{{ assetFingerprint("/client.js") }}"></script>
```

There is also [Static Expiry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-expiry) which works similarly.